# Unity2D cloned gameobject doesnt detect the tags of other gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a projectile that spawns and when it hits the player he gets destroyed. I have to mention that the projectile would be spawned with the "Instantiate" command making it a "cloned gameobject". In the script I wrote that if the projectile would hit another gameobject with the tag "player" the gameobject it hits would get destroyed but after running the code and the projectile hit the player he didn't get destroyed. I checked and the tag does say "player". I threw in a debug command into the code and managed to find out that the tag doesn't get detected. The script for the projectile spawner and the projectile itself are separate so I'm going to only show the projectile script since it is the problematic script. I have to mention that the script doesn't generate any errors and that the simulation runs fine except for the things I have mentioned above.

```
public class Bulletboi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Transform player;
    private Vector2 target;
    public GameObject Elven;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player").transform;
        target = new Vector2(player.position.x, player.position.y);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if(transform.position.x == target.x && transform.position.y == target.y)
        {
            DestroyProjectile();
        }
    }
    void OnEnterTrigger2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag.Equals("player"))
            {
            Debug.Log("bbbb");
            DestroyProjectile();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
    void DestroyProjectile()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it meets all collision requirements?

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning that I am new to unity and programming, but can you please specify the requirements that must be met for the code to work?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I decided to change the script a little bit and I put it on the player and made it detect the tag of the projectile and now it works.